# Header in resume template

Tags: header-footer, templates, resume

I am trying to insert a header on each page in the resume template: https://cs.overleaf.com/latex/templates/recent-grad-resume-template/gjxncvsftpqr. I would like the header to be at the very top of the page and look like this: [image]

I tried using the package fancyhdr, but it overlapped with the header that is already on the first page of the template. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to help https://cs.overleaf.com/2736785912swrgdnypghrc
Is it what You want?

Comment: Yes, this works! Thanks!